# 12.10 on Acer Apsire One D255

Tags: 12.10, aspire-one

Has anyone successfully run 12.10 on an Acer aspire one D255 (I have upgraded to 2GB ram)? 12.10 kept crashing after 2 to 5 minutes on mine, so I reloaded 12.04 which works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to install 12.04, you may try to upgrade to 12.10 instead of installing from scratch.

Your machine is supported. See the [Hardware support wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#Acer_Aspire_One_D255).

Now 12.04 is a Long-Term Support (LTS) release and therefore by default it will offer you to upgrade only for the next LTS version. So do the following:

1. Open **Update Manager**
2. Go to Settings and on the updates tab change the setting **Notify me of a new Ubuntu version** to **for any new version**
3. Check for updates and there should be an option to upgrade to 12.10.